# BubbleSort thread doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make a thread which will sort an array with the BubbleSort method, but I have some problems.

This is my BubbleSort class:

```
package thread;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BubbleSort implements Runnable {

private int[] array;
private long start, end;

public BubbleSort(int[] array){
    this.array=array;
}

public void sort(){
    int j;
    boolean flag = true;  
    int temp;

    while (flag) {
        flag= false;
        for( j=0;j<array.length-1;j++ ){
            if (array[j]>array[j+1]){
                temp = array[ j ];            
                array[j] = array[ j+1 ];
                array[j+1] = temp;
                flag=true;            
            } 
       } 
    } 
}

@Override
public void run() {
   start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   this.sort();
   end = System.currentTimeMillis();
   System.out.println(end-start);
}

public long getTime(){
    return end - start;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

}

and the main class:

```
package multisort;

import thread.BubbleSort;

    public class MultiSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {12,34,53,1,23,532,102,31,12,0,344,123,5422,12341,22,3410,123,342,233,12342,234432,12334};
        BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort(x);
        Thread bsThread = new Thread(bs);
        bsThread.start();
        System.out.println(bs+"\n"+bs.getTime());
        /*
        bs.sort();
        System.out.println(bs); it works
        */
    }

}
```

The problem is that the array will not be sorted if I call my sort method in the  run method. Who can help me with a response?

Comment: What sort of debugging have you tried?

Comment: "The problem is it doesn't work" is not helpful. You have to be much more specific about what *precisely* you expect and what *precisely* you get and then ask a specific question about what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't wait for the thread to finish sorting. You just stomp on the array regardless of what the other thread is doing!

This is like telling your daughter she can use the car and then opening the hood and taking out bits of the motor.